# Entity Framework 5 on .NET 4.0 - DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity is undefined

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I need to use EF5 on .NET 4 and I've run into a reference issue when mapping my class with HasDatabaseGenerationOption.Identity which doesn't exist in the 4.0 version of the library.

The following is failing:

```
this.Property(t => t.DeploymentLogId)
              .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 24):

Using NuGet to add EntityFramework to a project that targets .NET 4.5, will add EntityFramework 5.0.

If you later change the project to target .NET 4.0, EntityFramework 5.0 is still referenced.

To fix it, use NuGet to uninstall EntityFramework and add it back, also in NuGet. This will add EntityFramework 4.4 which is the last supported version for .NET 4.0.

If it still does not work there may be some references to the specific EF version in `App.config`. These can be removed.

Comment: That did it - I didn't have EF 5 installed. Type `Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre` into the PM.

Comment: Note: I had to remove EF for .NET 4.5 from all projects in my solution before readding it to get it working with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 11):

The namespace changed in EF 5.0. Try adding this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Comment: Again, that is a .NET 4.5 namespace.  I need 4.0.

Comment: No, that's an Entity Framework namespace. Have you tried it? I'm using this in a .NET 4.0 EF 5 project right now.

Comment: Hotrodmonkey,  .NET 4.0 supports a smaller feature set of EF 5.0, however, .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) is supported in EF 4.1+

Ultimately, you should accept @jrummell 's response as the answer.  If you're running into issues, make sure you're referencing EF 4.1+ in your application

I've been using it in an EF 4.x .NET 4.0 Production application for over a year.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a data annotation?

```
public class DeploymentLog
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DeploymentLogId { get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesn't live in 4.0 either

Comment: public class DatabaseGeneratedAttribute : Attribute
/ Name: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute 
/ Assembly: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` has only been a part of the .NET Framework since 4.5

If you're using 4.0 then Entity Framework will provide it for you. If you look at the source code of [DatabaseGeneratedOption](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a5faddeca2be#src/EntityFramework/DataAnnotations/Schema/DatabaseGeneratedOption.cs) and the other files, you'll see that their code is wrapped in a conditional

```
#if NET40
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

We had that problem very recently on an old project, and what we did was just

- delete the EntityFramework reference in the project
- right click on the project, do a Manage NuGet packages, go to the Updates category, and click Update on the Entity Framework item that was there in the list to version 6