# Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption' from assembly 'EntityFramework' error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET application which works fine using EntityFramework 4.3. I have it now use EntityFramework 6.0.2 instead. Now I am getting the error below at a line in the OnModelCreating code.

Why am I getting this error? Why is it looking for DatabaseGeneratedOption enum in EntityFramework assembly instead of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations? It seems .NET is confused somehow.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    ....
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}  <== errors here
```

**Error message:**
Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 5 on .NET 4.0 - DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183944/entity-framework-5-on-net-4-0-databasegeneratedoption-identity-is-undefined)

Comment: @Gert Not the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you removed all references to System.Data.Entity dll