# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Code

```
 using (TimeTableEntities obj = new TimeTableEntities())
    {
     var dataM=obj.LoginAccesses.Where(i =>(i.Salutation + ' ' + i.Fname + ' ' + i.Lname) == fname).ToList();
     foreach(var countTemp in dataM)
       {
        //mycode
       }
     }
```

Exception

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."
```

when I tried without where clause it work fine for me but when I added where it shows above Exception

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] and create new property to concat you data and use it in where cluase.

Comment: how to use ? any ex.

Answer (score 0):

in your Entity create new Proprty

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
 public string MyCombinationData{
    get{
          return Salutation  + ' ' + Fname + ' ' + Lname
    }
}
```

and in your query use this :

```
 var dataM=obj.LoginAccesses.Where(i =>i.MyCombinationData == fname).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi ,sorry for late  when  i tried your solution i got error  "databasegenerated namespace doesnot exist...."  like when search error I found that its work upto version EntityFramework 4.4 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12599605

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; in EF 6.1.3